# Trying to prove ¬A ∨ B from A → B, but a bit stuck on how to end the proof

Tags: logic, proof

This is my first time trying out proofs, and I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong, so criticism is happily received!

My proof so far is as follows:

1. A → B

Subproof 1:
2. A ∨ ¬ A [Assumption from L.E.M]

Subproof 1 of Subproof 1:

1. A [assumption]
2. B [→E 1,3]
3. ¬A ∨ B [∨I 4]

[End of subproof 1]

Subproof 2 of Subproof 1:

1. ¬A [assumption]
2. ¬A ∨ B. [∨I 6]

[End of subproof 2]

8. ¬A ∨ B [∨E 2, 3-5, 6-7]

I am not entirely sure how to continue this, as I am stuck in the first subproof. Using the forallx checker, it seems to work out so far, but I feel as if I am making some sort of fatal error that I am noticing right now. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The proof is correct. The result follows from LEM by D E.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's a relief, thank you. Although, I am still unsure as to how to close the subproof properly.

Comment: The proof holds in Classical Logic; LEM is an axiom and not an assumption to be closed.

Comment: @acompletethought does this give any clarity? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812067/prove-a-rightarrow-b-vdash-neg-a-vee-b-using-natural-deduction

Comment: is not the thing you want to proof already the "definition" of the operation. I think different texts start with different "definitions" and then "proorf" the others from this.

Comment: the subproof is closed properly at line 8. It can discharge both assumptions (line 3 and 6) because both subproofs reached the same conclusion. The lines and inference you cited at line 8 are correct.